# Resuming a git svn clone from revision number without repeats

Tags: git, svn, clone, fetch, git-svn

Disclaimer: I understand I can specify a revision number to clone from in the format `git svn clone svn://svn.server.com/project -s -r N:HEAD`. I also understand that `git svn fetch` continues a `git svn clone` without a revision from where it left off.

I have several questions:

1. If I do a `git svn clone` from a revision number and interrupt the clone, do I need to specify this revision number again in the fetch to continue? I'm concerned that if I don't the fetch will see I've missed history and start over.
2. If I specify a revision number in the fetch after interrupting the clone, will the fetch start again from that revision number or will it continue from where it left off?
3. Will I need to `rebase` when I'm done?

Thanks in advance, I've spent a fair amount of time googling this.

Comment: Whilst waiting to see if anyone knows the answer to this I'm going to try and set up an environment where I can do this myself and try to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up giving this a go myself. Answers:

1. You do not need to specify the revision number. If you have (for example) 20 revisions and do a clone from 10, and interrupt it at 11 running `git svn fetch` in the git repository will continue from revision 12.
2. Specifying the same revision as in the clone for the fetch continues the process as in 1.

As for the rebase question, I don't know.